# terraform route53 resolver setup

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

Just been trying to use the new terraform aws_route53_resolver_endpoint resource. It takes the subnet ids as a block type list. Unfortunately there appears to be no way to populate this from a list of subnets read from an output variable from the previous step.

Basically I have a set of subnets created using the count on the subnet resources in a previous step. Im trying to use these and setup aws_route53_resolver_endpoint in each of these subnets:

```
resource "null_resource" "management_subnet_list" {
  count = "${length(var.subnet_ids)}"

  triggers {
    subnet_id = "${element(data.terraform_remote_state.app_network.management_subnet_ids, count.index)}"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_resolver_endpoint" "dns_endpoint" {
  name               = "${var.environment_name}-${var.network_env}-dns"
  direction          = "OUTBOUND"
  security_group_ids = ["${var.security_groups}"]

  ip_address = "${null_resource.management_subnet_list.*.triggers}"
}
```

The above when run, results in an error: `ip_address: should be a list`

If I modify the code as follow:

```
ip_address = ["${null_resource.management_subnet_list.*.triggers}"]
```

I get the error: `ip_address: attribute supports 2 item as a minimum, config has 1 declared`

I can't seem to figure out any other way to create the resource list dynamically from a list of subnets.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting the list of subnets to change often? If so is it just the subnet IDs that will change or also the amount of subnets?

Comment: Looks like a case for Terraform 0.12's [`for` loops](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each) (it's currently in beta).

Comment: Yes, the list of subnets can vary between 2 or 3. I am managing the creation of on demand vpc's and in each VPC a team can decide to use 2 or three AZ, hence based on the subnets in 2 or 3 AZ I need to create the outbound resolver endpoints.  The terraform 0.12 dynamic block with for loop will work but we cant use terraform 0.12 for now.

Comment: without v0.12, you can work around with this https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14037#issuecomment-361202716

Answer (score 1):

Per the resource reference for [aws_route53_resolver_endpoint](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_resolver_endpoint), the `subnet_id` in the `ip_address` block is a single string value.

To specify multiple subnets, you need to have multiple `ip_address` blocks.

Since you state that you're creating subnets with a [count argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html), you could potentially reference each individually with the index like: `aws_subnet.main[0].id`, `aws_subnet.main[1].id` and so on, each in it's own `ip_address` block.  (or for Terraform 0.11, I think it was `"${aws_subnet.main.0.id}"`.)

However, a better way would be to use the [Dynamic Blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) available in Terraform 0.12 +

Dynamic Blocks allow you to create repeatable nested blocks within top-level blocks.(resource, data, provider, and provisioner blocks currently support dynamic blocks).

A dynamic `ip_address` block within the `aws_route53_resolver_endpoint` resource could look like:

```
  dynamic "ip_address" {
    for_each = aws_subnet.main[*].id
    iterator = subnet

    content {
      subnet_id = subnet.value
    }
  }
```

Which would result in a separate `ip_address` nested block for each subnet created in the `aws_subnet.main` resource.

The `for_each` argument is the complex value to iterate over. It accepts accepts any collection or structural value, typically a list or map with one element per desired nested block.

For complete info on the dynamic nested block expression, see the Terraform documentation at: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html